# How does the pushforward act on a differential form?

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, pushforward

Let $F:M\mapsto N$ be a smooth map of smooth manifolds and $\omega\in\Omega^k(M)$. In the lecture notes that I'm working with, I see the notation $F_*\omega$. I'm assuming that this is the push forward of $F$ acting on $\omega$ and I loosely understand what this map does, but I don't understand how one would define it rigorously and can't find anything about it online. Some help would be appreciated.

Comment: You can pullback a differential form by an arbitrary smooth map, but usually you only define pushforward of differential forms for specific types of smooth maps. The lecture notes don't define this notation?

Comment: The only way I know how to push forward a differential form is to assume the map is a diffeomorphism and pull back the form using the inverse map.

Comment: Can you share the notes?

Comment: As @MichaelAlbanese indicated, the notion of *integration over the fiber* (or the *Gysin map*) is associated to a more specific situation.

Comment: You have to decide what kind of properties such pushforward should have. For instance: Do you want the pushforward of a differential form to be again a differential form? I suggest you think about the following example: $M=(0,1), N={\mathbb R}$, $\omega=dx$ and $f(x)=x$ is the identity inclusion map. What would you regard as a valid pushforward $f_*(\omega)$?